# Visual Studio 2010 Plug-in - Adding a context-menu to the Editor Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, plugins

This is similar to the following question: [Visual Studio 2010 Plug-in - Adding a context-menu to the Solution Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017063/visual-studio-2010-plug-in-adding-a-context-menu-to-the-solution-explorer), however my query is how to add the item to the context menu item to the code editor window for JavaScript files.

I am attempting to add the context menu in with a Visual studio Add-in project (not a Visual studio package).

The code from the above link has been supremely helpful. To summarise, to add an item to the context menu of the Solution Explorer and Project explorer, we do so first by retrieving the items themselves:

```
CommandBars cmdBars = (CommandBars)(_applicationObject.CommandBars);
CommandBar vsBarProject = cmdBars["Project"];
CommandBar vsBarSolution = cmdBars["Solution"];
```

And later on, adding them adding them in by augmenting the readily available project template code:

```
command.AddControl(vsBarProject);
command.AddControl(vsBarSolution);
```

Now my query is regarding which of the `cmdBars` elements I have to add the command to, in order for my item to appear on the context menu for editing script files

I have already established its not `cmdBars["Code Window"]`. Is there one item for all files, or do I have to add it for each editor type (e.g. ASPX, Script, HTML, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context menu associated specifically with editing of Script files (and by association, JavaScript files) is `cmdBars["Script Context"]`

In order to find this, I added the new menu item to all (465) menu controls in visual studio with the following loop

```
foreach (CommandBar cc in cmdBars)
{
    if (cc.Index >= 1 && cc.Index <= 465)
    {
        command.AddControl(cmdBars[cc.NameLocal]);
    }
}
```

I then narrowed this using a divide and conquer technique by adjusting the bounds of the loop:

```
    if (cc.Index >= 1 && cc.Index <= 256)
    ...
    if (cc.Index >= 1 && cc.Index <= 128)
    ...
    if (cc.Index >= 64 && cc.Index <= 128)
    ...etc...
```

Until I eventually found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

This is the complete list of names and indices. Maybe this can help someone.

```
Index: 1 Menu Bar
Index: 2 Standard
Index: 3 Build
Index: 4 Class View Multi-select Project references Items
Index: 5 Class View Multi-select Project references members
Index: 6 Context Menus
Index: 7 &Sort By
Index: 8 Show &Columns
Index: 9 Project
Index: 10 Error List
Index: 11 Docked Window
Index: 12 Menu Designer
Index: 13 Properties Window
Index: 14 Toolbox
Index: 15 Code Window
Index: 16 Task List
Index: 17 Results List
Index: 18 Stub Project
Index: 19 Solution
Index: 20 Solution Folder
Index: 21 Cross Project Solution Project
Index: 22 Cross Project Solution Item
Index: 23 Cross Project Project Item
Index: 24 Cross Project Multi Project
Index: 25 Cross Project Multi Item
Index: 26 No Commands Available
Index: 27 Misc Files Project
Index: 28 Cross Project Multi Solution Folder
Index: 29 Cross Project Multi Project/Folder
Index: 30 Command Window
Index: 31 AutoHidden Windows
Index: 32 Expansion Manager
Index: 33 Find Regular Expression Builder
Index: 34 Replace Regular Expression Builder
Index: 35 Wild Card Expression Builder
Index: 36 Wild Card Expression Builder
Index: 37 External Tools Arguments
Index: 38 External Tools Directories
Index: 39 Easy MDI Tool Window
Index: 40 Easy MDI Document Window
Index: 41 Easy MDI Dragging
Index: 42 Open Drop Down
Index: 43 Item
Index: 44 Folder
Index: 45 Class View Project
Index: 46 Class View Item
Index: 47 Class View Folder
Index: 48 Class View Grouping Folder
Index: 49 Class View Multi-select
Index: 50 Class View Multi-select members
Index: 51 Class View Member
Index: 52 Class View Grouping Members
Index: 53 Class View Project References Folder
Index: 54 Class View Project Reference
Index: 55 Class View Project Reference Item
Index: 56 Class View Project Reference Member
Index: 57 Object Browser Objects Pane
Index: 58 Object Browser Members Pane
Index: 59 Object Browser Description Pane
Index: 60 Find Symbol
Index: 61 Reference Root
Index: 62 Reference Item
Index: 63 Web Reference Folder
Index: 64 App Designer Folder
Index: 65 Drag and Drop
Index: 66 Web Project Folder
Index: 67 Web Folder
Index: 68 Web Item
Index: 69 Bookmark Window
Index: 70 Web SubWeb
Index: 71 Error Correction
Index: 72 Other Context Menus
Index: 73 Class View Context Menus
Index: 74 Project and Solution Context Menus
Index: 75 Editor Context Menus
Index: 76 EzMDI Files
Index: 77 Ca&ll Browser
Index: 78 Preview Changes
Index: 79 Team Project
Index: 80 Team Project &Settings
Index: 81 &Team Project Collection Settings
Index: 82 Toolbar List
Index: 83 Undefined
Index: 84 SchemaExplorer
Index: 85 ContentModelView
Index: 86 GraphView
Index: 87 FilmstripView
Index: 88 Test Results Context Menu
Index: 89 Test List Editor Context Menu
Index: 90 Test List Context Menu
Index: 91 Test Run Context Menu
Index: 92 View Context Menu
Index: 93 Code Coverage Results Context Menu
Index: 94 Cr&eate Private Accessor
Index: 95 Test Results Context Menu
Index: 96 Test Tools
Index: 97 Selection
Index: 98 &Zoom
Index: 99 Page Layout
Index: 100 Designer Actions
Index: 101 &Navigation Tools
Index: 102 Workflow
Index: 103 Directed Graph
Index: 104 Directed Graph Context Menu
Index: 105 &Group
Index: 106 &Categorize
Index: 107 &Selection
Index: 108 Architecture Explorer Context Menu
Index: 109 &Generate Dependency Graph
Index: 110 A&nalyzers
Index: 111 &Goto
Index: 112 Architecture Designers
Index: 113 XAML Editor
Index: 114 Checkin Dialog Context Menu
Index: 115 Pending Checkin Window Context Menu
Index: 116 Standard TreeGrid context menu
Index: 117 GetVersion Dialog Context Menu
Index: 118 Check Out Dialog Context Menu
Index: 119 Source Control
Index: 120 Text Editor
Index: 121 Formatting
Index: 122 Context
Index: 123 Context
Index: 124 Basic Context
Index: 125 HTML Context
Index: 126 Script Context
Index: 127 ASPX Context
Index: 128 ASPX Code Context
Index: 129 ASPX VB Code Context
Index: 130 ASMX Code Context
Index: 131 ASMX VB Code Context
Index: 132 ASAX Context
Index: 133 ASAX Code Context
Index: 134 ASAX VB Code Context
Index: 135 Context
Index: 136 Context
Index: 137 HTML Source Editing
Index: 138 XML Editor
Index: 139 Debugger Context Menus
Index: 140 Step Into Speci&fic
Index: 141 Debug Location
Index: 142 Debug
Index: 143 Watch Window
Index: 144 Locals Window
Index: 145 Autos Window
Index: 146 Threads Window
Index: 147 Call Stack Window
Index: 148 Disassembly Window
Index: 149 Breakpoints Window
Index: 150 Memory Window
Index: 151 Registers Window
Index: 152 Modules Window
Index: 153 Data Tip Window
Index: 154 Processes Window
Index: 155 Breakpoint
Index: 156 Output Window
Index: 157 Script Project
Index: 158 Thread Tip Window
Index: 159 Thread IP Marker
Index: 160 Thread IP Markers
Index: 161 Load Symbols From
Index: 162 Symbol Include List
Index: 163 Symbol Exclude List
Index: 164 TocContext
Index: 165 ResListContext
Index: 166 Change &View
Index: 167 Static Node
Index: 168 Object Node
Index: 169 Multiple Static Nodes
Index: 170 Multiple Homogenous Object Nodes
Index: 171 Multiple Heterogenous Object Nodes
Index: 172 Multiple Heterogenous Nodes
Index: 173 Add &New
Index: 174 Data Design
Index: 175 Surface
Index: 176 DataSourceContext
Index: 177 DbTableContext
Index: 178 DataTableContext
Index: 179 RelationContext
Index: 180 FunctionContext
Index: 181 ColumnContext
Index: 182 QueryContext
Index: 183 DataAccessorContext
Index: 184 Server Explorer
Index: 185 Query Designer
Index: 186 Query Diagram Pane
Index: 187 Query Diagram Table
Index: 188 Query Diagram Table Column
Index: 189 Query Diagram Join Line
Index: 190 Query Diagram Multi-select
Index: 191 Query Grid Pane
Index: 192 Query SQL Pane
Index: 193 Query Results Pane
Index: 194 View Designer
Index: 195 Database Diagram
Index: 196 Database Designer
Index: 197 Database Designer Table
Index: 198 Database Designer Relationship
Index: 199 Text Annotation
Index: 200 Table Designer
Index: 201 Database Project
Index: 202 DB Project Connection
Index: 203 DB Project Folder
Index: 204 Database References Folder
Index: 205 Folders
Index: 206 DB Project File
Index: 207 Query
Index: 208 Script
Index: 209 Database Reference Node
Index: 210 Files
Index: 211 Multi-select
Index: 212 PropertyBrowser
Index: 213 Selection
Index: 214 Container
Index: 215 TraySelection
Index: 216 Document Outline
Index: 217 Component Tray
Index: 218 Layout
Index: 219 Editor
Index: 220 Script Outline
Index: 221 Web Browser
Index: 222 DefaultContext
Index: 223 ImageContext
Index: 224 SelectionContext
Index: 225 AnchorContext
Index: 226 Debugger Project Context Menu
Index: 227 DataTips Context
Index: 228 Watch Item Context
Index: 229 Text Box Context
Index: 230 Call Hierarchy Context Menu
Index: 231 Parallel Tasks Window Context Menu
Index: 232 Tasks List Column Header Context Menu
Index: 233 Stacks Window Context Menu
Index: 234 Switch To Frame
Index: 235 Control
Index: 236 Report
Index: 237 Report Formatting
Index: 238 Row/Column
Index: 239 Cell
Index: 240 Field Chooser
Index: 241 Report Borders
Index: 242 Row/Column
Index: 243 Chart
Index: 244 Report
Index: 245 &Registry
Index: 246 &New
Index: 247 &File System
Index: 248 &File System
Index: 249 &Add
Index: 250 &View
Index: 251 &Add Special Folder
Index: 252 &File Types
Index: 253 &User Interface
Index: 254 &Launch Conditions
Index: 255 &Custom Actions
Index: 256 Project Node
Index: 257 E&ditor
Index: 258 A&dd
Index: 259 Cab Project Node
Index: 260 A&dd
Index: 261 Vie&w
Index: 262 File nodes
Index: 263 Dep. file nodes
Index: 264 Assembly nodes
Index: 265 Dep. assembly nodes
Index: 266 MSM nodes
Index: 267 Dep. MSM nodes
Index: 268 Output nodes
Index: 269 Simple file nodes
Index: 270 Simple output nodes
Index: 271 Dependency node
Index: 272 Multiple selections
Index: 273 Dep. Multiple selections
Index: 274 CSSDocOutline
Index: 275 CSSSource
Index: 276 Style Sheet
Index: 277 Dialog Editor
Index: 278 Resource View
Index: 279 Resource Editors
Index: 280 Resource Dialog Editors
Index: 281 Image Editor
Index: 282 Ribbon Editor
Index: 283 Resource Ribbon Editors
Index: 284 Binary Editor
Index: 285 ORDesigner Context
Index: 286 ORDesigner Context
Index: 287 ORDesigner Context
Index: 288 Propertysheet
Index: 289 Configuration
Index: 290 Project
Index: 291 Multi-Select
Index: 292 System Propertysheet
Index: 293 Exe Project
Index: 294 Debug
Index: 295 &Refactor
Index: 296 Smart Tag
Index: 297 Re&solve
Index: 298 &Implement Interface
Index: 299 &Organize Usings
Index: 300 G&enerate
Index: 301 References
Index: 302 Web Platform Installer
Index: 303 Web One Click Publish
Index: 304 Channels
Index: 305 Call Stack Report
Index: 306 Process Tree
Index: 307 Selection Panel
Index: 308 Binaries
Index: 309 Binary
Index: 310 Reports
Index: 311 Report
Index: 312 Session
Index: 313 Binary
Index: 314 Test Project
Index: 315 Create Work Item
Index: 316 Test Project
Index: 317 Marks
Index: 318 Summary
Index: 319 Module
Index: 320 Function
Index: 321 Butterfly
Index: 322 Calltree
Index: 323 Type
Index: 324 Lifetime
Index: 325 ProcessThreads
Index: 326 Views
Index: 327 Query
Index: 328 QueryControl
Index: 329 Line
Index: 330 IP
Index: 331 Marks
Index: 332 Diff
Index: 333 Contention
Index: 334 CounterChart
Index: 335 Boundary
Index: 336 IntelliTrace
Index: 337 Content Pane Context Menu
Index: 338 Context Pane Context Menu
Index: 339 Code Metrics Context Menu
Index: 340 Test Context
Index: 341 Code Change Context
Index: 342 Team Explorer - Builds
Index: 343 Team Explorer - Build Definition
Index: 344 Team Explorer - All Build Definitions
Index: 345 Build Explorer
Index: 346 &Sort By
Index: 347 Set Priorit&y
Index: 348 Build Queue Explorer
Index: 349 Team Explorer Multiple Items
Index: 350 Team Foundation Context Menus
Index: 351 Team Foundation Server
Index: 352 My Favorites
Index: 353 My Favorites Folder
Index: 354 Favorite
Index: 355 Documents
Index: 356 Documents Folder
Index: 357 Document File
Index: 358 Reports
Index: 359 Report
Index: 360 Report Folder
Index: 361 Source Control Explorer
Index: 362 Source Control Explorer Command Holder
Index: 363 Pending Changes Command Holder
Index: 364 Source Control Pending Changes Source Files
Index: 365 Compare
Index: 366 Source Control Pending Changes Work Items
Index: 367 Source Control Pending Changes Policy Warnings
Index: 368 Source Control History Changesets
Index: 369 Source Control History Labels
Index: 370 Annotate
Index: 371 Annotate
Index: 372 S&ource Control
Index: 373 Folder Difference
Index: 374 ConfigureUserTools
Index: 375 Online
Index: 376 Compare
Index: 377 Source Control Pending Changes Conflicts
Index: 378 Compare
Index: 379 Branch Visualizer
Index: 380 &Branching and Merging
Index: 381 Hierarchy Visualizer
Index: 382 Label
Index: 383 Branch Visualizer Command Holder
Index: 384 &Branching and Merging
Index: 385 Mappings
Index: 386 Checkin Dialog Context Menu
Index: 387 Pending Checkin Window Context Menu
Index: 388 Standard TreeGrid context menu
Index: 389 GetVersion Dialog Context Menu
Index: 390 Check Out Dialog Context Menu
Index: 391 Source Control - Team Foundation
Index: 392 Work Item Tracking
Index: 393 Work Items
Index: 394 Query Folder
Index: 395 Query
Index: 396 Query Builder
Index: 397 Results List
Index: 398 Work Item
Index: 399 Links Control
Index: 400 Results List Column Sort
Index: 401 New Work &Item
Index: 402 &Clauses
Index: 403 New Work Item
Index: 404 Lin&ks
Index: 405 Attac&hments
Index: 406 E&xpand/Collapse
Index: 407 Recorder
Index: 408 Macro
Index: 409 Module
Index: 410 Project
Index: 411 Root
Index: 412 SequenceDesigner Context
Index: 413 UseCaseModel Context
Index: 414 SmartTag
Index: 415 LogicalClassDesigner Context
Index: 416 ActivityDesigner Context
Index: 417 SmartTag
Index: 418 ComponentDesigner Context
Index: 419 LayerDesigner Context
Index: 420 Layer Explorer Context Menu
Index: 421 Model Explorer Context Menu
Index: 422 Data Sources
Index: 423 Managed Resources Editor Context Menu
Index: 424 Settings Designer
Index: 425 My Extensibility
Index: 426 Discover Service References
Index: 427 ClassDesignerContextMenu
Index: 428 ClassDiagramContextMenu
Index: 429 Class Designer
Index: 430 ClassDetailsContextMenu
Index: 431 &Generate Code for Coded UI Test
Index: 432 Load Test Editor Context Menu
Index: 433 Web Test Editor Context Menu
Index: 434 Run Test
Index: 435 Load Test Monitor Context Menu
Index: 436 Web Test Result Context Menu
Index: 437 Test Steps Context Menu
Index: 438 Test Parameters Context Menu
Index: 439 Test Data Context Menu
Index: 440 MicrosoftDataEntityDesign Context
Index: 441 MicrosoftDataEntityDesign Context
Index: 442 Web Deploy Project
Index: 443 &AnkhSVN Context Menus
Index: 444 Repository Explorer
Index: 445 Working Copy Explorer
Index: 446 &Pending Commits
Index: 447 Pending Commits &Header
Index: 448 Log Message Editor
Index: 449 Log Viewer List
Index: 450 Log Viewer Changed Paths
Index: 451 Listview Header
Index: 452 Annotate Context Menu
Index: 453 Source Control - Subversion
Index: 454 SqlEditorContextMenu
Index: 455 SqlEditorResultsContextMenu
Index: 456 SqlDebuggerContextMenu
```