# Add a custom menu item to the Context Menu in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenu

I have a windows application. Now When I right click on the file, I am getting a context menu.

[image]

What I want is to add a custom menu item in that built in Context Menu. e.g. "My custom Menu " in this case.

[image]

How can I do this? Any link or some sort of reference point will be very helpful. I am using C#

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to develope a visual studio extension?

Comment: Is this something you want only in **your visual studio IDE** or are you trying to **write code** which will perform this operation?

Comment: @Blachshma , need to add it only in the visual studio IDE

Comment: all you want ot add new extension for visual studio. take a google for How to create Visual studio extionsion. take a look here for sample. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12244/Adding-Menu-Items-to-context-menus-inside-the-Visu

Comment: Sir, the point is that, I need to attach the menu item inside teh built in menu items. As directed by @Blachshma, but i need to do that at runtime. so that when the application will be deployed, the menu should come. How to achieve that?

Comment: why dont you record a macro and add that to you context menu. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967(v=vs.80)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add a context menu **in code using C#**:

Here is a good reference: [Visual Studio 2010 Plug-in - Adding a context-menu to the Solution Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017063/visual-studio-2010-plug-in-adding-a-context-menu-to-the-solution-explorer)

If you **only want this in your IDE**:

Go to `Tools -> Customize`

2. Choose Commands
3. Choose the appropriate context menu
4. Add a new menu / command - depending on what exactly you need

[image]

Comment: sir, thanks . I am looking for this. But how to do the same programatically.