# Add menu item to .cs files (only) in Visual Studio solution explorer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I want to add a context menu item to .cs files in solution explorer in VS 2010? I could add it to the project, but not only to .cs files? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017063/visual-studio-2010-plug-in-adding-a-context-menu-to-the-solution-explorer

Answer (score 0):

In your `OnBeforeQueryStatus` Method you need to get the currently selected object and determine the file type, then you can set the Visible property for the `MenuCommand`.

To enabled `OnBeforeQueryStatus` you will need to add the following Attribute to your package:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.UIContextGuids.SolutionExists)]
public sealed class YourPackage : Package
```

Then in your Command Constructor you will need to bind your callback to `BeforeQueryStatus`:

```
... 
    var commandService = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
    if (commandService == null) return;
    var menuCommandId = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
    var menuItem = new OleMenuCommand(this.MenuItemCallback, menuCommandId);
    menuItem.BeforeQueryStatus +=
        new EventHandler(OnBeforeQueryStatus);
    commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
...
```

OnBeforeQueryStatus:

```
private void OnBeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myCommand = sender as OleMenuCommand;
    if (null == myCommand) return;
    var selectedObject = Util.GetProjectItem();
    myCommand.Visible = selectedObject.Name.EndsWith(".cs") && this.Enabled;
}
```

GetProjectItem:

```
public static ProjectItem GetProjectItem()
{
    IntPtr hierarchyPointer, selectionContainerPointer;
    Object selectedObject = null;
    IVsMultiItemSelect multiItemSelect;
    uint projectItemId;

    var monitorSelection =
        (IVsMonitorSelection)Package.GetGlobalService(
            typeof(SVsShellMonitorSelection));

    monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection(out hierarchyPointer,
        out projectItemId,
        out multiItemSelect,
        out selectionContainerPointer);

    var selectedHierarchy = Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(
        hierarchyPointer,
        typeof(IVsHierarchy)) as IVsHierarchy;

    if (selectedHierarchy != null)
    {
        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(selectedHierarchy.GetProperty(
            projectItemId,
            (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject,
            out selectedObject));

    }
    return selectedObject as ProjectItem;
}
```

And with all of that you should be only seeing your button on project files that end with `.cs`